# Embeded Watson Virtual Agent chatbot missing response

Tags: virtual, agent, watson, watson-virtual-agent

I've created an html file with embedded Watson Virtual Agent chat bot, code similar below, with WVA strictly using the building core capabilities:

IBMChat.init({
    el: 'ibm_chat_root',
    baseURL: 'https://api.ibm.com/virtualagent/run/api/v1',
    botID: '',
    XIBMClientID: '',
    XIBMClientSecret: ''
  });

What I noticed is if I run the WVA in Preview mode, and have input "pay bill", the WVA can come back with two piece response, with first:

> Accessing your account information...

and second the make payment:

> Your account balance is $42.01 due on 5/17/2017. What would you like to do? (More options coming soon!)

However, if I enter the same in my HTML chatbot, the response only comes back with the first part:

> Accessing your account information...

and second part never comes out.

Does anyone else experience the same problem?

Comment: Has anyone tried to test an embedded WVA chatbot?  It seems to me the standalone chatbot behaves differently than running WVA in Preview mode, the standalone chat bot always has trouble receiving the 2nd part of response.

Answer (score 0):

The version in the "Preview" mode has some mock "action" handlers setup. Obviously, not every one of you users would owe $42! In the sample code on the github, the mock action handlers are not setup. There are examples on how to subscribe to those action events with handlers here: https://github.com/watson-virtual-agents/chat-widget/tree/master/examples/basic-actions-example

As of 5/31/17 you can cover all the built in actions using the code snippet below...

```
const config = { instance: null };

const getUserProfileVariablesMap = {
    'bill_amount': '42.01',
    'payment_due_date': (() => {
        const currentDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        return `${currentDate.getMonth() + 1}/${currentDate.getDate()}/${currentDate.getFullYear()}`;
})(),
    'authorized_users': 'Bob Everyman and Jane Doe'
};

const getUserProfileVariables = (data) => {
    const variables = data.message.action.args.variables;
    variables.forEach(v => {
        const value = getUserProfileVariablesMap[v];
        (value) ? config.instance.profile.set(v, value) : config.instance.profile.set(v, '[sample data]');
    });
    config.instance.sendSilently('success');
};

const success = () => config.instance.sendSilently('success');
const agent = () => config.instance.receive('On your own site you would run code to connect to an agent now.');
const accountSettings = () => config.instance.receive('On your own site you would run code to open the Account Settings page now.');

function registerActions(instance) {
    config.instance = instance;
    instance.subscribe('action:getUserProfileVariables', getUserProfileVariables);
    instance.subscribe('action:updateAddress', success);
    instance.subscribe('action:updateUserName', success);
    instance.subscribe('action:updatePhoneNumber', success);
    instance.subscribe('action:updateEmail', success);
    instance.subscribe('action:payBill', success);
    instance.subscribe('action:sendPaymentReceipt', success);
    instance.subscribe('action:agent', agent);
    instance.subscribe('action:openAccountSettingsPage', accountSettings);
};

window.IBMChatActions = {
    registerActions: registerActions
};

// window.IBMChatActions.registerActions(window.IBMChat);
```

Answer (score 0):

On the Administrative Preview, you are getting fake code stubs that handle action requests from the agent.

When one of these actions are invoked, the widget will print the "Processing..." message and then invoke all registered subscribers for that action.  It is up to these registered subscribers to continue the conversation flow by silently sending `"success"`, `"failure"`, or `"cancel"` back to the server.

For example, the agent might pass down the `"payBill"` action.  You would want to call your payment gateway, determine if it was successful, and then notify the agent of the result:

```
IBMChat.init(/* Settings */);

IBMChat.subscribe('action:payBill', function() {
  var data = {
    amount: IBMChat.profile.get('amount'),
    card: {
      number: IBMChat.profile.get('cc_number'),
      // ... other private card data
    }
  };
  $.post('https://www.myserver.com/payment-gateway', data)
   .done( function() {
     IBMChat.sendSilently('success');
   })
   .fail( function() {
     IBMChat.sendSilently('failure');
   });
});
```

**Actions Documentation**
https://github.com/watson-virtual-agents/chat-widget/blob/master/docs/DOCS.md#actions